# g++ "because the following virtual functions are pure" with abstract base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, diamond-problem

Here is my example code which produces the error:

```
struct Impl
{
  int data_size_;
  int find(int var){return 0;}
  int get(int rowid){return 0;}
};

class Container
{
public:
  Container() {}
  virtual ~Container() {}
  virtual int get_size() = 0;
  virtual int get(int rowid) = 0;
};


class SortedContainer : virtual public Container {
public:
  virtual int find(int var) = 0;
};

class ContainerImpl : public Container
{
protected:
  Impl impl_;
public:
  int get_size() {return impl_.data_size_;}
  int get(int rowid) {return impl_.get(rowid);}
};

class SortedContainerImpl
  : public SortedContainer, public ContainerImpl
{
private:
  typedef ContainerImpl Base;
public:
  int find(int var){return Base::impl_.find(var);}
};

ContainerImpl ci;
SortedContainerImpl sci;
```

it seems "SortedContainerImpl" went wrong while "ContainerImpl" is fine.

g++ complains:

```
example_b.cpp:42:21: error: cannot declare variable ‘sci’ to be of abstract type ‘SortedContainerImpl’
example_b.cpp:32:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘SortedContainerImpl’:
example_b.cpp:13:15: note:  virtual int Container::get_size()
example_b.cpp:14:15: note:  virtual int Container::get(int)
```

I inheret SortedContainerImpl from ContainerImpl in order to reuse get_size() and get(int)

I'm not familiar with c++, What's the nature of this problem and How can I fix it?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `SortedContainerImpl` class has two separate `Container` base classes.  One is virtual (via the `SortedContainer` class) and the other is non-virtual (via the `ContainerImpl` class).

`SortedContainerImpl` has concrete implementations of `Container::get_size()` and `Container::get(int)` for the base that comes in from `ContainerImpl`, but not for the virtual base that comes in via `SortedContainer`.

One way to fix the problem is to give concrete implementations in `SortedContainerImpl`:

```
class SortedContainerImpl
  : public SortedContainer, public ContainerImpl
{
private:
  typedef ContainerImpl Base;
public:
  int find(int var){return Base::impl_.find(var);}

  int get_size() {return ContainerImpl::get_size();}
  int get(int rowid) {return ContainerImpl::get(rowid);}
};
```

Another way would be to make `Container` a virtual base class of `ContainerImpl`, so `SortedContainerImpl` would only get the one, virtual, base `Container`:

```
class ContainerImpl : virtual public Container
{
protected:
  Impl impl_;
public:
  int get_size() {return impl_.data_size_;}
  int get(int rowid) {return impl_.get(rowid);}
};
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems your answer is right. Should I really just make all interface classes virtually inherited everywhere?

Answer (score 25):

In C++, once you have a pure virtual member function, your class becomes an abstract class and you cannot create any objects from it. Such a class is not meant to be instantiable by itself. It is meant to act as an **Interface**. One would derive from such an abstract class and **provide implementations of all the pure virtual functions in the derived class**.

Note that your class `SortedContainerImpl` derives from two classes `SortedContainer` and `ContainerImpl`. `SortedContainer` in turn derives from `Container` but it never implements the pure virtual functions.