# error: no ‘’ member function declared in class ''

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual

I'm trying to create a class containing a virtual function, which i would like to inherit in two child classes.

I know some people already asked this ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375560/error-because-function-is-pure-virtual-within-class) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615904/g-because-the-following-virtual-functions-are-pure-with-abstract-base-class) for example), but i couldn't understand the answers.

So i made a simplified example code of what i'm trying :

```
//Mother .h file 

#ifndef _MOTHER_H_
#define _MOTHER_H_
#include <iostream>

class Mother
{
 protected :
   std::string _name;
 public:
   Mother(std::string name);
   ~Mother();
   virtual std::string getName() = 0; 
};

#endif

//Mother .cpp file

#include "Mother.h"

Mother::Mother(std::string name)
{
  this->_name = name; 
}

Mother::~Mother()
{
}


//Child.h file

#ifndef _CHILD_H_
#define _CHILD_H_
#include "Mother.h"

class Child : public Mother
{
 private : 
   std::string _name;
 public:
   Child(std::string name);
   ~Child();
};

#endif


//Child .cpp file

#include "Mother.h"
#include "Child.h"

Child::Child(std::string name) : Mother(name)
{
  this->_name = name;
}

Child::~Child()
{
}

std::string Mother::getName()
{
  return this->_name;
}
```

Here is my main.cpp file :

```
//Main.cpp file
#include "Child.h"

int main()
{
   Child l("lol");

   std::cout << l.getName() << std::endl;

   Mother& f = l;

   std::cout << f.getName() << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Here's what the compilator says : 
**(compiling with g++ *.cpp -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror)**

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:9: error: cannot declare variable ‘l’ to be of abstract type‘Child’
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Child.h:8:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Child’:
In file included from Child.h:6:0,
             from main.cpp:1:
Mother.h:14:23: note:   virtual std::string Mother::getName()
```

What am i doing wrong ?

(sorry if i made some  english mistakes, i am not a native speaker).

Comment: You have not overridden the pure virtual function getName() in your child class.

Comment: You need to implement getName() function in your child class.

Comment: Why is getName() pure at all?

Comment: Children don't really inherit from mothers in the OOP world.

Comment: @Joker_vD This is assignment that i have to do, so getName has to be pure...

Comment: @AbhishekBansal but that's what i did? no? or shouldn't i inherit from mother, and just rewrite it in the Child?

Comment: @progo:  They might when they die. :~

Comment: The names of your include guards use reserved identifiers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Mother`'s declaration you have:

```
virtual std::string getName() = 0;
```

This is not just a `virtual`, but a **pure** `virtual`.  The distinction between a `virtual` and a **pure** `virtual` is that the pure variety *must* have an override implemented in a derived class, even if you have provided an implementation in the base class.  For example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  virtual void DoIt() = 0 {};  // pure virtual.  Must be overridden in the derived class even though there is an implementation here
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
public:
  void DoIt(); // override of base
};

void Bar::DoIt()
{
  // implementation of override
}
```

You can't instantiate a class with un-implemented pure `virtual` methods.  If you try, you will get a compiler error:

```
int main()
{
  Foo f;  // ERROR
  Bar b;  // OK
}
```

And that is exactly what you tried to do.  You declared `getName()` to be **pure** `virtual` in 
`Mother`, but you did not override it in `Child`.  Then you tried to instantiate a `Child`

```
int main()
{
   Child l("lol");
```

Which resulted in the compiler error.

To fix it, provide an override of `getName()` in the `Child` class.

Comment: `std::string Child::getName() { return Mother::getName(); }`?

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now i understood my mistake ! :)
I still don't understand the logic behind it, but now i now how to use it.

Comment: @Joker_vD: that won't compile.  There's no implementation in 'Mother'

Comment: @JohnDibling There is, scroll down the code in the question all the way down.

Comment: @Joker_vD:  Ah, yes, I had missed that.

Answer (score 3):

You `class child` should override `getName()` method as it is `pure virtual` defined in `class` `mother`

Seems typo to me.. as `std::string Mother::getName()` is defined in `child.cpp`..

```
std::string Child::getName()
{
  return this->_name;
}
```

Comment: Well... this worked... but what's the point of redefining the Function in the Child if i already defined it in the Mother class?

Comment: Infact that is wrong.. there should be no function name getName in class mother... as it is pure virtual (body =0). In this example, there must be only one getName ..and that must be in Child!

Comment: @Digital_Reality Well, having definition for pure virtual function *in the class where it was declared* is not against the standard. It would allow you to implement `Child::getName` as `return Mother::getName()`.

Comment: @Joker_vD yes but I am not really sure, if defining a pure virtual function does makes any sense!!

Answer (score 0):

The pure virtual function in your base class Mother does not make sense from an OOP perspective, it is a common trait in all children so the same function could be used. There is no need to override it.

```
struct Person
{
  Person(std::string name) : _name(name) {}
  std::string _name;
  std::string getName() {return _name; }
};

struct Mother : Human
{
   Mother(std::string name) : Person(name) {}
};

struct Child : Human
{
   Child(std::string name) : Person(name) {}
};
```